# How to create a text file with the date and time as the title

Tags: python, windows-7, python-3.3

i have looked and i have found many answers for python 2.7 but i have yet to find one in 3.3

Criteria:

i can follow it

```
title = Date+Time
```

Able to save in a certain directory

Available in Python 3.3.1 WITHOUT plugins/downloads/etc.

(if one already exists either post it here or link it.
(please be wary of future visitors

My Use:
Make a txt file on one pc with date and time then put it on my ftp then pull it off onto my computer.

Thanks.

(On Windows 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import os, time
>>> path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
>>> fname = time.ctime().replace(':', '-') + '.txt'
>>> with open(os.path.join(path, fname), 'w') as f:
...   pass
```

Comment: Thanks but i get this error: http://pastebin.com/DDL0jRW6

Comment: try the updated version